# Git frontend that supports Diffs after a rename

Tags: git, user-interface, rename

My team used to rely on EGit to provide us with diffs between different versions of a file. This no longer works after the project layout was changed by moving files from `Project/src/....` to `Project/src/main/java/....`.

After this bulk rename, we can no longer compare versions of a file to each other, either with EGit or instaweb. The only way to get a proper diff now is from the command line:

```
$ git diff -M SHA1:old_path/file.java SHA2:new_path/file.java
```

The problem is that we need to do a lot of these, so the loss of GUI support is a serious productivity hit.

I have tried using GitEye and SmartGit, but neither of these could figure out the renames either.

I am curious if anyone has ever been able to get GUI diffs working across renames with any tool. If so, please tell me what tool and how you did it.

Comment: To people voting to close as off-topic: how is this question not about "[software tools commonly used by programmers; and [...]
a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)"?

Answer (score -1):

Try gitg or gitk for visual representation.